# How to enable nested json result in OData (ASP.NET Core API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm using the following controller to get data from database using EF Core:

```
public class EquipmentsController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly SqlServerContext _sqlServerContext;

        public EquipmentsController(SqlServerContext sqlServerContext)
        {
            _sqlServerContext = sqlServerContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public ActionResult<IQueryable<Equipment>> Get()
        {
            IQueryable<Equipment> eqList = _sqlServerContext.Equipments.AsQueryable()
                .Include(x => x.CostCenter)
                .Include(x => x.EquipmentCategory)
                .Include(x => x.equipmentType);

            return Ok(eqList);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I cannot get nested result in the final json while I have included `CostCenter`, `EquipmentCategory`, and `equipmentType` entities.
I'm using ASP.NET Core 6 API and OData 8.0.12
How can I fix that?

**Update**: My ED model is as follows:

```
static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new();
    builder.EntitySet<Equipment>("Equipments");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `get nested result in the final json` ? The JSON format is specified in the OData schema, not the LINQ code. What does your OData query look like? An OData query doesn't expand (include) related objects by default. The client has to ask for this explicitly, and the server needs to be configured to allow it

Comment: Check the [OData Expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/odata-expand) page in the docs and notice that the controller returns an `IQueryable` directly, not an ActionResult. `[HttpGet, EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Enrollment> Get([FromServices]SchoolContext context) 
    => context.Enrollment;`. The ODataController will apply the client query on the IQueryable returns by the action marked with `EnableQuery`. If the query asks to expand, it will apply `Include` if and as needed

Comment: Thanks. Solved. Please add your solution in the Answers section.